# Porque eu não consigo ler esse arquivo com fstream?

Tags: c++

Eu estou estudando a parte de entrada e saída arquivos em C++, porém me encontro com um pequeno problema.
Estou tentando fazer com que o programa leia um arquivo de chamado "nome.txt" com 10 nomes dentro dele, mas por algum motivo ele não esta conseguindo fazer isso, quando eu faço o teste ele nem chega a entrar no if/else. Ele cria o arquivo com os nomes normalmente mas não consegue imprimir o que esta dentro dele

```
fstream arquivo;
arquivo.open("nome.txt", ios::out);
arquivo << "Diego\n";
arquivo << "Thales\n";
arquivo << "Vitor\n";
arquivo << "Lais\n";
arquivo << "Rodrigo\n";
arquivo << "Karen\n";
arquivo << "Larissa\n";
arquivo << "Thiago\n";
arquivo << "Gabriel\n";
arquivo << "Arthur\n";

string line;
arquivo.open("nome.txt", ios::in);
if(arquivo.is_open())
{
    while(getline(arquivo, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "erro: não foi possivel encontrar os nomes";
}
arquivo.close();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Você não deveria fechar o arquivo após grava-lo para só então abri-lo como leitura?

Comment: era isso mesmo, acabei esquecendo. Obrigado!